# Condition between two timestamp with timezone

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.14

I have next sql:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow';
select t.* 
from duty_room.incident t 
where t.incident_start_time 
   between timestamp with time zone '2022-01-01 00:00:00+03:00' 
       and timestamp with time zone '2022-10-24 23:59:59.999999999+03:00'
```

It fetchs:

```
+---+---------------------------------+
|id |incident_start_time              |
+---+---------------------------------+
|446|2022-10-25 00:00:00.000000 +03:00|
+---+---------------------------------+
```

Why it fetchs a row with 2022-10-25 date?

**Table definition:**

```
create table incident
(
    id                          bigserial
        primary key,
    incident_card_id            varchar(20),
    incident_name               varchar,
    incident_start_time         timestamp with time zone not null,
    incident_end_time           timestamp with time zone,
...
```

Comment: Show table definition (its CREATE TABLE), at least the definition for `incident_start_time` column.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! [Can't reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/jj5Iwy98) - maybe a test case from db<>fiddle might be good?

Comment: @Alkina see my update

Comment: [Proof](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ZtDaNOR) of what @LaurenzAlbe is saying. I was going to say myself that `BETWEEN` using TIMESTAMP(TZ)'s is **never** a good idea! Always use `>=` with `<` and you won't go wrong!

Answer (score 4):

That is because timestamps only have microsecond precision in PostgreSQL. Your timestamp will be rounded up:

```
SELECT timestamp with time zone '2022-10-24 23:59:59.999999999+03:00';

      timestamptz       
════════════════════════
 2022-10-25 00:00:00+03
(1 row)
```